# Show/hide DIV in a date range & time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Hi Everyone at Stackoverflow.

After loads of searches I am really stuck. I want to do some kind of image rotator script of where the DIV changes on the Date/time range so after 12am the div changes class to close rather than open.

http://www.diggerland.com

Any ideas how to achieve this? I just need to know what route to go down.

Regards,
Joe

Comment: Try using the moment library: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know if this is what you are looking for, but here is an example i made in fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/01830zuj/

```
function ShowOnTime(from, to, element){

    var a = new Date(); 
    var now = a.getHours(); //local hours. For GMT use .getUTCHours()

    if( now < from || now > to ){
        $(element).hide();
    }else{
        $(element).show();
    }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ShowOnTime(10,13,"#TestDiv"); 
});
```

With this function you can just enter the time interval and element that you want to show.

For some reason it does not hide it in fiddle, but i tested it on my live website and it's working just fine there.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Im going to have a play around it! Cheers for that again.